# Как добавить ко всем дубликатам в Map суффикс

Tags: java, потоки-данных, map

Предположим, что на вход метода приходят айдишники, одни из которых имеют суффикс, а другие нет

Set **ids** = [id, id::Suff]

Далее мне нужно создать Map<String, Object>, где ключом будет id.

Но перед этим нужно удалить все id с суффиксом.

```
Map<String, Object> idToObj =
                ids.stream()
                        .map(IdExtractor::removeSuffix)
                        .map(id -> Pair.of(id, getObj()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                  _________ ,
                                Pair::getRight
                        ));
```

Не могу разобраться, как правильно собрать ключи и вернуть суффикс для нужных id

Заранее спасибо

Comment: в таком виде сложно понять, что вы вообще делаете. к примеру, что это Set ids = [id, id::Suff] ? Или вот этот метод IdExtractor::removeSuffix? Напишите метод , принимающий ваш сет, реализуйте его своим способом и добавьте класс IdExtractor. иначе достаточно сложно дать корретктный ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если идентификаторы с суффиксом не нужны, проще отфильтровать их при помощи `Stream::filter`.
Также нет необходимости создавать экземпляр `Pair` перед использованием коллектора `toMap`:

```java
Map<String, Object> idToObj =
        ids.stream()
            .filter(id -> !id.matches("\\w+::\\w+")) // или любой другой способ
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                id -> id,
                id -> getObj()
        ));
```